# Why do people use the term "free gift'?

Tags: expressions

I see and hear the term "Free Gift".  Are not all gifts free?

Comment: You'd be surprised.  Sometimes, to get your "free gift," you have to sit through a 90-minute hard-sell timeshare presentation.

Comment: Usually when they use the term it means you're going to pay for it somehow.

Comment: Yes, but that's to clarify against the *special purchases* that require you to get both to get the special price... In other words, you buy the shoes, you get the belt for free, vs. buy the shoes and the belt at this special price. It's about attracting the buyer while minimizing the bewaring.

Comment: Ask a Trojan.  Oh, wait.  You can't.  They took that free horse.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how "If you buy more than one, your savings increase!" makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

A "Free Gift" may sound tautologous, but it also sounds profitable.  Advertising copy writers know that people respond to the word "free" the way a hungry dog responds to a meatloaf.

The *Huffington Post* cites a book by Dan Ariely, *Predictably Irrational*, in which a study demonstrated the selling power of the word ***free***.

(See http://www.huffingtonpost.com/gregory-ciotti/copywriting-for-business_b_2286336.html)

*For what it's worth, the "free gift" probably isn't, at least if the putative giver has their way!"*

Comment: And "free" isn't necessarily without ambiguity which is why in my days as a copywriter for a large retail catalog, we were strictly forbidden from using "free" when offering something for no charge, such as buy one/get one.  Per our legal department, we had to use clunky language or disclaimers such as "at no extra charge", "complementary", etc.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Been there, used to to do that too! *Shipping and handling not included, must be 18 or over to win, not available in all locations, and may be hazardous to house plants...*   :-0